# Are there any podcast apps that allow playing podcasts at accelerated speed?

Tags: podcast

I have BeyondPod for my Android, which lets me speed up the playback 1.5 or 2 times normal speed. Is there any Windows Phone app that has this feature?

Answer (score 3):

The default Podcast app in Windows Phone 8.1 does already support playing audio at 1,5x speed. As Jordax mentioned you can change it to 2x by tapping the 1,5x twice.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in Windows Phone 8.1 Podcasts app supports this.

Beside the podcast artwork display, there is a grey "1.5x" label. Press this once to select it (it goes white) and playback runs at 1.5x speed; press it again and it switches to 2x speed. Press it once more to deactivate it (switches back to grey "1.5x").